# Cannot export Canvas to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js

I'm trying to print a canvas in a PDF file that I'm creating. The issue is that I always get a black rectangle in my PDF instead of the graph that I can see on my web page.

I generate the canvas like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 featurePanel" style="display: none;">
    <div id="canvasContainer_@featureID"></div>
</div>
```

It's filled by JS:

```
function SetFeatureValues(measID, measIndex, measCount, featureID, canvasID, name, humL, humR, femL, femR, thor, lumb, reference, type, color, ResTable) {

    if (ResTable.length == measCount) {
        var element = document.createElement("canvas");
        element.id = canvasID;
        element.classList.add("ThreeDDogGraph");
        document.getElementById('canvasContainer_' + featureID).appendChild(element);
        _3ddogvis.scene(0.0, true, ResTable, canvasID);
    }
}
```

Then I export it to a PDF file:

```
function RenderFeature(pdf, currentTopPosition, currentLeftPasition, canvas) {    
    var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
    newCanvas.width = width;
    newCanvas.height = height;
    context.drawImage(document.querySelector('#' + canvas.id), 0, 0, width, height);
    var newCanvasImg = newCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    pdf.addImage(newCanvasImg, 'png', currentLeftPasition, currentTopPosition, graphWidth, graphHeight, undefined, 'FAST');

}
```

After downloading the file I get a black rectangle in my PDF with the dimensions of my canvas.

EDIT:
If I try to copy the canvas (as propose obscure) I also get a black picture and the error message:

```
Unable to clone WebGL context as it has preserveDrawingBuffer=false
```

As I use a library done by someone else, I cannot set the preserveDrawingBuffer to true.
Is there a solution to get a picture from a canvas with preserveDrawingBuffer set to false?

Comment: Did you try appending your temporary canvas to the DOM to see if it ain't black? `document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);`

Comment: @obscure I tried and get a black picture too. But I also get the error message: Unable to clone WebGL context as it has preserveDrawingBuffer=false.